# How to handle the errors inside for loop while getting inputs empty using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, multiple-input

Hope someone can advise.

I'm facing a small issue of handling errors while the `inputs` are empty inside the for loop.
I have to use for loop in this case because I'm inserting multiple inputs in the same time.

On checking if inputs are empty the only thing is happen is looping on nothing just loop and return nothing.

PHP code:

```php
public function Add_new_order($tableno, $cashier_name, $date, $time, $name, $quantity, $price, $sub_total, $total) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(order_num) AS order_number FROM all_orders");
    $stmt->execute(); 
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $order_num = $row["order_number"];
        if(is_null($order_num)) {
            $order_num = '100000';
        }
        else {
            $order_num += 1;
        }   
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++) {   
        if($quantity[$i] > 0) {
            if($name[$i] != "" && !empty($quantity[$i]) && $price[$i] != "") {
                $stmt1 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `all_orders` (`ID`, `order_num`, `tablenum`,`cashier_name`, `date`, `time`, `item_name`, `item_code`, `quantity`, `price`, `total`) VALUES ('','".$order_num."','".$tableno."','".$cashier_name."','".$date."','".$time."','".$name[$i]."','','".$quantity[$i]."','".$price[$i]."','".$sub_total[$i]."')");
                $stmt1->execute();                         
            } 
        } else {
            $this->Error_msg('Error.'); 
        }        
    }
    
    $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `biling`(`ID`, `order_num`, `tablenum`,`cashier_name`, `date`, `time`, `total`) VALUES ('','".$order_num."','".$tableno."','".$cashier_name."','".$date."','".$time."','".$total."')");
    $stmt2->execute();
    if($stmt1 && $stmt2) {
        $this->Success_msg('Done.');
    } else {
        $this->Error_msg('Error occurred.');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can perform multiple row inserts at the same time using comma separated bracket notations in your values... `insert into blah (cola,colb,colc) values (val1a,val1b,val1c),(val2a,val2b,val2c),(val3a,val3b,val3c)`

Comment: What if I'm inserting unknown numbers of rows. Which is I already did, I'm inserting dynamic inputs

Comment: You're using prepared statements so why aren't you binding parameters?

Comment: Actually it's working without binding parameters. Is that necessary in this case or it's ok if not binding?

Comment: You're doing a lot in that one function.  For example, the first query will only have one result: the max order_number.  Pull that out in its own method and then all you have to do is `$order_num = $this->getMaxOrderNumber();` .  You can also break out the first `insert` into its own method and then just call that method within the loop.  Same with the second; make its own method, called if there are values.  It isn't as efficient as the way described above, but it's doubtful that it would be noticeable.

Comment: re: binding.  Yes, it works as you are doing it; but it is insecure.  You're asking for SQL injection.

Comment: @TimMorton I will.

Comment: @HazemBehairy well with a dynamic number of items to insert you can still build a single insert statement, think of prepared statement as a template, build your template first then bind the values to it.

Comment: @Scuzzy make sense to me. I'll try it.